# Configure Django's test debugging to print shorter paths.

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm not sure how to approach this, whether it's a Django, Python, or even Terminal solution that I can tweak.

The thing is I'm learning Django following a book (reference [here](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/pages/book.html), really like it), and whenever I run the tests, I get really long output in the terminal for debugging matters.  Obviously there's many traceback functions that get called after another, but what started bugging me is that the file paths are very long and they all have the same project folder... which is long by itself, and then it adds all the virtualenv stuff like this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "home/user/code/projects/type_of_projects_like_hobby/my_project_application/this_django_version/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)`

Since the paths take two or more lines, I can't focus on what functions I should be looking at clearly.

I have looked at the verbosity option when calling `manage.py test` but it doesn't help with the paths.  If anyone has an idea on how to ~fix~ go about this issue, it'd be cool.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not a way to change the behavior (this is how Python displays tracebacks). But you *can* pipe the output into something that will reformat it. For example, [here's a tool you can pipe traceback output into that will do various types of formatting](https://github.com/nir0s/backtrace).

Comment: This definitely looks like the think I want.  Although I'll take some time to implement it. Thanks.